# How to sort a QuantumGrid on data from a different column

Tags: delphi, grid, delphi-2010, devexpress, quantumgrid

Is there a way to sort Devexpress QuantumGrid rows on data from a different column other than the one whose header has been clicked? For example, when the header of column A is clicked the rows of the grid are sorted on the data from column B. Visually it should still appear that it is column A that has been sorted as the sort glyphys will be shown in column A's header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@norgepaul you must check the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) for the questions related to the DevExress products, This site has thousands of answers and articles related to its products.

check theses links

- [Sorting by other field (when clicking header) in ExpressGrid 6](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/AQ16058.aspx?searchtext=sort&p=T1|P0|83)
- http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/SearchResults.aspx?searchtext=sort&p=T1|P0|83

Answer (score 0):

I don't have DevExpress here to check, but i would look to see if there is a custom sort event.  like OnCustomSort, where you get to decide whether a value or cell sorts higher or lower. I think you'll have the ability to know what rows are being compared, so you could look across to B cells, and make your own comparision.